# NextJs AppRouter

Tags: next.js, app-router

[app file organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJkiD.png)I am trying to create a new page in Next JS 13 but when I create a folder and subsequently a new page.jsx, it just routes to the bottom of the main page rather than a new URL. I am not sure what I need to change.

I created the new folder as suggested in the Vercel Documentation with a new page.jsx but it just routes to the bottom of the main page.

please see the below snippet for file organization. conversely, my link tag is in my projects component like:

```
<ProjectItem
            title="Whats Hop"
            tech="React.TSX/Firebase/MongoDB"
            backgroundIMG="/assets/whatshop.png"
            projectURL="/whatshop"
          />
```

Comment: Can you share a screen shot of how you've structured your files & folders, plus how you are linking to the new page/route?

Comment: I included the code snippet and a picture

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new page, you have to create a folder and inside create a file called page.js
example
posts/page.js
this automaticaly create a route
then you can test
http://localhost:3000/post

Comment: I tried that an it just recreates the page in a new url with a div at the bottom